# Exclude a certain file or directory while copying from a Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I wish to copy all files except a certain directory or directories (or files) from my GCS bucket to my local directory. Is there anyway I can do the same?

For example:
My GCS bucket named `so-bucket` has three folders `dir1`, `dir2`, `dir3`, `file1` and `file2`. I want to copy all the files and directories except `dir3` from the bucket to my local directory.

Usually I would do `gsutil -m cp -r gs://so-bucket/* .` and then delete the `dir3` folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`gsutil rsync`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) command, with `-x` option to exclude some objects. Something like :

```
gsutil -m rsync -r -x '^dir3/*' gs://so-bucket .
```

should retrieve all objects located on the bucket, except objects beginning with `dir3` (files not located in `dir3` directory in your example).